# How to keep async system.net.socket listener alive in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets

I'm using multi threaded system.net.socket to listen on a single port. I want to catch simultaneous requests from multiple clients. Here is my sample:

```
private static ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        Thread threadListener = new Thread(program.StartListening);
        threadListener.Start();
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
         IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["httpPort"].ToString()));

         Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

         listener.Blocking = false;
         listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
         listener.Listen(10);

         listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
         _manualResetEvent.Set();

         Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

         Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

         StateObject state = new StateObject();
         state.workSocket = handler;

         handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

         listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        StateObject state = null;
        Socket handler = null;

        try
        {
            state = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
            handler = state.workSocket;

            int numBytesReceived = handler.EndReceive(result);

            if (!handler.Connected)
            {
                handler.Close();
                return;
            }

            if (numBytesReceived > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, numBytesReceived));

                string[] lines = state.sb.ToString().Split('\n');

                if (lines[lines.Length-1] == "EOF")
                {
                    // Do something according to client request
                }
                else
                {
                    // We didn't receive all data. Continue receiving...
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            // Don't care
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

The problem is that I cannot keep the application running with just using these codes. If I run this application and catch a client request, my ReceiveCallBack method works correctly and the application stops after a successfull execution.

I can use the sample code in this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep my application alive. It uses a while loop in StartListening method as you can see below:

```
while (true) 
{
     allDone.Reset();
     listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
     allDone.WaitOne();
}
```

But it seems that MSDN designed this code for a blocking listener. I mean it does not allow simultaneous connections. So it is not appropriate for me.

I have to prevent my application from stopping after execution of my codes without while loop in MSDN sample. I have to keep it running and listening for multiple simultaneous connections continuously.

So how can I keep that application running?

Thanks

Comment: What exception message are you seeing? Post it and the stacktrace.

Comment: Exception is about another thread which does not affect us now. I just wanted to say that application remains open because of that thread. Actually forget about it. Maybe it was wrong to mention about it in that question.

Comment: So your problem is that the application simply hangs? On which line?

Comment: @Yuval thanks for your interest and it seems I choose wrong words to define my problems today. I will be back after 30 mins. You can see my edited question. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the problem. Note that if your problem is simply that the program exits, then you probably just need to change your code so that at least one operation is synchronous (in a simple server, this would often be the accept loop...i.e. just dedicate a thread to calling `listener.Accept()`). But without a complete example, it's impossible to know for sure what's going on.

Comment: @Peter I edited the question. I removed try catch blocks and comments etc. Thats all I can do. This is a general async socket example. Question is clear. How to keep my codes running continuously without blocking simultaneous connections.

Comment: @OrkunBekar I don't seen anything in the code you posted that would stop the application. This code will keep on accepting clients forever, so the problem isn't with that part. If the application stops for some other reason, then that code needs to be seen. And the MSDN code is not designed for a blocking listener and allows as many connections as you want. It just accepts the first one, then you just `BeginAccept` again.

Comment: Is it because listener is established as a local variable in each routine and maybe disposed after ? I've got a similar working socket code but my listener is declared outside the two routines.

Comment: @Andrew no I tried listener as global variable I think it is not problem.

Comment: @Sami this is a Windows application which does not have forms. So if you don't put a while loop or something similar it stops normally.

Comment: @OrkunBekar So just use BeginAccept, then wait for an object that will be set only when you want it to exit. And actually the MSDN code is not suitable for that, since you don't need the whole while loop at all if you BeginAccept again in the callback.

Comment: @OrkunBekar You don't even need async in this case at all. You can just Accept in a loop and then call BeginReceive to handle it async from that point onwards.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen but I have to accept simultaneous requests of clients. If I don't use async then I will reply their requests in turn.

Comment: @OrkunBekar You accept a connection, set the receive to async, accept another, receive in async and so on. You will then handle all connections at the same time. You can't anyway handle accepting connections simultaenously, they're always sequential. It's about the actual data transfer that will be async and run simultaenously.

Comment: is the problem with how you're handling sockets or, is it how to keep the program running ? Ie, have you got means of the progam running indefinately perhaps a while loop on another thread that does some sort of keep alive ?

Comment: @Andrew that' right I keep it alive with another thread but I don't want to depend on it.

Comment: Please re-read the link I provided above. You have edited the question, but still have not provided **a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho For example what do you want to see additionally? ReceiveCallBack method? Adding it is not necessary. Is there extra, unnecessary code? Didn't you like its format? I looked at the link but I could not understand what you don't like about my question. Make it clear please.

Comment: IMHO the linked article is very clear. But the short version is: the code you posted, someone else should be able to copy and paste it whole into a blank project, and then run it. **No extra work.** For networking examples, this means you have to provide both the **server** and the **client**. And both must be **minimal** as well as **complete**. Do not include parts of the program that are not strictly required to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I edited it again. I hope it is OK now.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added StateObject just now. I forgot it.

Comment: The MSDN samples are so incredible. Seeing the weird events stuff there makes my mouth open every time. The guy who wrote that had no idea what he was doing.

Comment: Giving a vote for closing question is easier than helping if you don't have an idea. I really respect that behaviour.

Comment: @OrkunBekar you are not entitled to receiving help. On Stack Overflow experts answer your question that cost 100-200$/h normally. Make it worth their time.

Comment: @usr do they earn money by answering questions?

Comment: @OrkunBekar no, they have fun. Sifting through tons of code only to find a very common mistake is not fun. It's rote work, not a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no thread that keeps your process alive. After a very short while only thread-pool threads are around and the runtime shuts down.

Starting a new thread from Main accomplishes nothing. Tell me what you thought this was supposed to achieve and I'll clear up the misunderstanding. Main should look like `StartListening(); Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);`. (Counter-intuitive!)

Besides that the code is workable although of low quality. Too many issues for me to comment in detail. Submit this to Codereview SE.

Comment: Anything differs if I put Application.Run() instead of Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite) ?

Comment: That would be fine too. Note, that as soon as that Run call exits the process shuts down. The point is not letting the thread die. It does not matter what you put there.

Comment: Can I save the application from closing in Thread exit event etc? How can I handle it? If it goes into threadexit event then I guess everything is over?

Comment: That's not the right approach. Why react if you can simply keep the app alive deterministically?